# Babel duplicates all class functions

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

```
export class Product extends IfcObject {
   constructor(){
     super(..)
     ..
   }
    calculatePolygon() {..}
}
```

When babel transpiles this to ES5 and I search for "calculatePolygon", I find 93 matches. It seems all class functions get copied to all classes that inherit from it.

The result is my bundle file gets huge. I understand es5 has no module-system but the solution cant seriously is to copy everything?

Have I done a config mistake?

This is my build in gulp:

```
gulp.task("babel", function () {
  return gulp.src(src)
    //.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(browserify({
      transform:['babelify']
    }))
    //.pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("out"));
});
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete input file and the transpiled output.

Comment: It seems questionable that you're using a Babel pipe *and* Babelify - surely you'd only need one or the other? Either way, I wasn't able to replicate your issue in the [REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl), so you'll need to provide more details, as Bergi suggested.

Comment: Do you use some Babel plugins or presets? Seems to work fine with both `es2015` and `env` presets (Babel creates and uses `_inherits` function in the output instead of copying everything): https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEBiCWAnCAXaBvAUNH0AmA9gMoEC2ApigBbwB2A5gBQCUG2uAkIpQK6K0YwALmgBGAL4BudjnGY5mUJBhFywArTzRyADxTlNMBMjRZc-YmUo0GAURARyLNuZzcUfAegBGIgExSMtByckA&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=env&targets=&version=6.26.0 (pls. select the preset manually, it doesn't load it from the url params for some reason)